# How to get AccessToken to post to Twitter after Authorization Succeeds

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth

This has been very painful. I don't know what I'm doing wrong with the AccessToken, but I try to set it before I call Twitter4j's updateStatus to post to twitter.

I tried different ways of getting the AccessToken's, I'm only using Twitter4J.

```
AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(), verifier);
```

Gives error:

```
05-09 12:06:45.776: D/GameName(678): Received authentication challenge is null
```

I am able to switch to the twitter browser for Authorization. I enter my user name and password, press "Authorize App". Then the browser changes to "redirecting" back to my app. My app appears and boom! It crashes! My app has called onNewIntent.

Code to Authorize works good:
(twitter is a member variable)

```
    public void twitterAuthorize() 
    {   
        try 
        {
            twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
            twitter.setOAuthConsumer(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);

            RequestToken requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(Constants.OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL);                         
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(requestToken.getAuthorizationURL())), TWITTER_AUTHORIZE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_CODE); 
        } 
        catch (TwitterException e) 
        { 
                Log.d(Globals.sApplicationName, e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();                 
        }       

    }
```

Returning from Authorization, I get to the line with "AccessToken accessToken =...", an exception is thrown.

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) 
{
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    Log.d(Globals.sApplicationName, "ENTERED: onNewIntent");

    Uri uri = intent.getData();
    if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(Constants.OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL)) 
    {
        Log.d(Globals.sApplicationName, "oAuth: " + uri.toString());
        String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");

        try {
            if (verifier != null)
            {
                Log.d(Globals.sApplicationName, "Verifier: " + verifier);


                //Try 1: doesn't work
                //AccessToken a = new AccessToken(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);

                //Try 2: doesn't work               
                AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(), verifier);

                //Try 3: doesn't work
                //String token = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_token");      
                //AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(token, verifier);

                //twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();

                twitter.setOAuthConsumer(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
                twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);

                // create a tweet
                Date d = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
                String tweet = "#OAuth working! " + d.toLocaleString();

                // send the tweet
                twitter.updateStatus(tweet);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.d(Globals.sApplicationName, e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I get these errors on the callstack (I just replaced the  so I keep it private from this forum post):

```
05-09 12:06:45.136: D/GameName(678): ENTERED: onNewIntent
05-09 12:06:45.136: D/GameName(678): oAuth: GameNameTwitterOAuth://callback?oauth_token=<some long string>&oauth_verifier=<some long string>
05-09 12:06:45.156: D/GameName(678): Verifier: <some long string>
05-09 12:06:45.747: W/AudioFlinger(32): write blocked for 131 msecs, 825 delayed writes, thread 0xff88
05-09 12:06:45.776: D/GameName(678): Received authentication challenge is null
05-09 12:06:45.846: W/System.err(678): Received authentication challenge is nullRelevant discussions can be on the Internet at:
05-09 12:06:45.846: W/System.err(678):  http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=bfb606ed or
05-09 12:06:45.856: W/System.err(678):  http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=72d7e395
05-09 12:06:45.856: W/System.err(678): TwitterException{exceptionCode=[bfb606ed-72d7e395 e2110e48-e8248ad2], statusCode=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, featureSpecificRateLimitStatus=null, version=2.2.5}
05-09 12:06:45.856: W/System.err(678):  at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:200)
05-09 12:06:45.856: W/System.err(678):  at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:65)
05-09 12:06:45.856: W/System.err(678):  at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.post(HttpClientWrapper.java:102)
05-09 12:06:45.856: W/System.err(678):  at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthRequestToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:121)
05-09 12:06:45.856: W/System.err(678):  at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthRequestToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:104)
05-09 12:06:45.856: W/System.err(678):  at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(TwitterBaseImpl.java:276)
05-09 12:06:45.856: W/System.err(678):  at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(TwitterBaseImpl.java:269)
05-09 12:06:45.856: W/System.err(678):  at com.mnecreations.panarchyfling.PanarchyFling.onNewIntent(PanarchyFling.java:602)
05-09 12:06:45.869: W/System.err(678):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnNewIntent(Instrumentation.java:1122)
05-09 12:06:45.869: W/System.err(678):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverNewIntents(ActivityThread.java:1812)
05-09 12:06:45.869: W/System.err(678):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performNewIntents(ActivityThread.java:1825)
05-09 12:06:45.869: W/System.err(678):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleNewIntent(ActivityThread.java:1834)
05-09 12:06:45.876: W/System.err(678):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-09 12:06:45.876: W/System.err(678):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1040)
05-09 12:06:45.876: W/System.err(678):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-09 12:06:45.876: W/System.err(678):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
05-09 12:06:45.876: W/System.err(678):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
05-09 12:06:45.876: W/System.err(678):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-09 12:06:45.876: W/System.err(678):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
05-09 12:06:45.896: W/System.err(678):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
05-09 12:06:45.896: W/System.err(678):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
05-09 12:06:45.896: W/System.err(678):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-09 12:06:45.896: W/System.err(678): Caused by: java.io.IOException: Received authentication challenge is null
05-09 12:06:45.896: W/System.err(678):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.processAuthHeader(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1176)
05-09 12:06:45.896: W/System.err(678):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.processResponseHeaders(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1118)
05-09 12:06:45.896: W/System.err(678):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.retrieveResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1044)
05-09 12:06:45.896: W/System.err(678):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:736)
05-09 12:06:45.906: W/System.err(678):  at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpResponseImpl.<init>(HttpResponseImpl.java:35)
05-09 12:06:45.906: W/System.err(678):  at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:164)
05-09 12:06:45.906: W/System.err(678):  ... 21 more
05-09 12:06:45.906: D/GameName(678): --------------------------------------------
05-09 12:06:45.906: D/GameName(678): Restart activity GameName
```

Please advise, this is really confusing. I looked at other posts and they mention stuff about time stamp, but that doesn't make sense to me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you are generating a new request token that has nothing to do with the verifier you have.

Try saving the twitter object and the token you've requested the first time and try to do something like this:

1. List item
2. get twitter object from twitter factory with consumerkey and consumerkeysecret
3. get requesttoken (twitter.getrequesttoken())
4. ask requesttoken for a auth url
5. save twitterobject and requesttoken
6. go to twitter and validate
7. return via callback and retrieve verifier
8. get saved twitterobject and requesttoken
9. those saved twitterobject and requesttoken should be used along with verifier to validate the user....

Then you are authenticated